# i want to add a search bar on top of my list view in class (i don't have a layout, i creating the list view in class)

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext, searchbar

for (int i = 1; i <= totalfriends; i++) {

```
// Cast the integer into a string.
Integer j = new Integer(i);
// We need to retrieve the JSONObject but it's first
// stored in an array.
JSONArray friendarray = obj.getJSONArray(j.toString());
JSONObject friendobject = friendarray.getJSONObject(0);
fname = friendobject.getString("firstname");
lname = friendobject.getString("lastname");
uid = friendobject.getString("uid");
contactNameList.add(fname + " " + lname);
contactIdList.add(uid);
// add to arraylist
//Store the above in a data structure}
```

contactMenu = contactNameList.toArray(new String[contactNameList.size()]);
idMenu = contactIdList.toArray(new String[contactIdList.size()]);
contactAdapter = new ArrayAdapter

```
// After store everything into datastructure, put the code
                // inside run() and loop again and display the friendlist.
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        setListAdapter(contactAdapter);
                        // Here, loop through the data structure and setup
                        // the friend list.

                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either:

1. Make a vertical LinearLayout, place your search bar as the first child, and place the ListView as the second child.
2. Call ListView.addHeaderView() on the ListView before you set it's adapter. In this case your search view (whatever that may be, an Edittext perhaps) will scroll with the rest of the items in the list
3. If you have an ActionBar, put an item in the action bar to allow for searching.

Comment: thanks for your reply,but i found out mine was  ListAdapter ,is it the same with list view